# logger(java.util.logging) suddenly stops printing the output into the console though it printing in the file

Tags: java, logging, jsch, java.util.logging

I'm using java.util.logging to set up the logger and here's the code :
           `fh = new FileHandler(file.getAbsolutePath());
            logger.addHandler(fh);
            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            fh.setFormatter(formatter);
            logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);`
The logger works fine with console and file .but after the below JSch code snippet 
        `Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

```
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(cmd1);

    channel.setInputStream(null);
    ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

    logger.info("creating tar ,executing command :"+cmd1);

    channel.connect();

    while (true) {
        if (channel.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println( logger.getHandlers());
            // doesn't log afterwards
             logger.info("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
            if (channel.getExitStatus() == 0)
                logger.info("tar file with " + tarFileName
                        + "has been created successfully at " + path);
            break;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception ee) {
        }
    }`
```

I guess the handler has changed when I'm executing the command.How can I reset the handler such that it starts printing into the console as well.

Comment: Have you declared all of your loggers as [`private static final` so they are not garbage collected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689831/log-file-not-being-updated-after-few-seconds-while-using-logger-and-filehandler)

Comment: yes , The logger is private static and is defined as :

Comment: private static Logger logger;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSch channel.disconnect prevent logs from printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229001/jsch-channel-disconnect-prevent-logs-from-printing)

Answer (score 1):

As described in [JSch channel.disconnect prevent logs from printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229001/jsch-channel-disconnect-prevent-logs-from-printing)

You have to change:

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
```

to

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err, true);
```

Otherwise `System.err` is closed when the channel is closed which will happen on exit.  Closing `System.err` will prevent you from seeing output on the console.

Another option would be to wrap `System.err` in a stream that ignores calls to close.